# Developer Console can SELECT or COUNT() more than 50.000 records. Why not Apex?

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, developer-console

For years people were looking for ways to query more than 50.000 records in Salesforce without running into `Too many query rows: 50001`. Event doing a COUNT() query was impossible.

By accident, I just did a query on a type with more than 1 million records. In the Query Editor of the Dev Console. And it worked!

When I tried the same in Apex it failed as expected. **Why?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apex uses more resources than a simple API call, such as extra memory, CPU time, etc, so there's additional limits in place. The Developer Console, contrariwise, uses the API, which is just a server-side database cursor. As such, you can technically query up to 50,000,000 rows in the Developer Console (though very large queries may time out or freeze your browser).

Comment: But would this be a hack to do a "SELECT Count() FROM Account LIMIT 50001" in Apex using the Tooling API?

Comment: @RobertSösemann You could do it in certain contexts, but you might get a recursive callout error or a DML not committed error. It's probably safe in Visualforce contexts, though, if you wanted to.

Comment: Though with VF, you can use the readonly mode to get 1 million rows I think?

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Certainly, but then you're in read-only mode. So it might be useful if you need to write data back later, or need to get more than 1 million rows, etc.

Comment: @sfdcfox - agreed, though that point, I think it is time to look at Batch or something else...